# CSS stack HTML 5 canvases and add a margin

Tags: css

I'm using multiple stacked HTML `canvas` elements to draw in my app. I would like the canvases to fit to the width and height of containing div while at the same time maintaining a left and bottom margin.

Here's a pseudo HTML:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <canvas></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

I would like the result to look like this:

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you do not set a width/height to the `canvas` it will default to it's natural size (300px x 150px).

So position the element as you require or `inset` by the required "margin" and use `calc` to set the width/height.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

div {
  margin: 1em auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: lightgreen;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 0 10px 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```